# dplyr where in other table

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for dplyr's variant to the SQL `where in` clause.

My goal is to look filter rows based upon their presence in a column of an other table. The code I have currently returns an error. I am guessing this is due to incorrectly pulling out the data from the second table to compare to the first.

```
Instruments %>% filter(name %in% distinct(Musician$plays_instrument))
```

I wrote an example similar to what I've got currently above this line. I am guessing that my mistake can be see in the syntax I am using. If not I can provide a working example if needed. Just takes some time to build it and I was hoping I got get this solved more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should use `unique` since `distinct` requires a dataframe as first argument.

```
library(dplyr)
Instruments %>% filter(name %in% unique(Musician$plays_instrument))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` in `base R`

```
subset(Instruments, name %in% unique(Musician$plays_instrument))
```